# Using EF 6.2 with MySQL and SQL Server from within one application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I started creating an app using EF 6.2 (.NET 4.8) and legacy MySQL database. Everything is OK. Also using AspIdentity using MySQL. All good. Recently it became apparent that I will need to connect to SQL Server to retrieve some additional data.

I could swear I've done this before and had either no or minimal issues. I currently can't get this to work.

I've looked into/at solutions overriding/creating

```
DataContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
```

in code and in `web.config`.

Seems no matter what I do, EF insist on connecting to MySQL and crashes and burns with assorted errors depending on where I am in my attempted solution.

Current error is:

> An instance of 'MySqlEFConfiguration' was set but this type was not discovered in the same assembly as the 'WmMainContext' context. Either put the DbConfiguration type in the same assembly as the DbContext type, use DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the DbContext type to specify the DbConfiguration type, or set the DbConfiguration type in the config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.

Yes, I've followed that link and tried to use it to solve my issue, but I had no success.

Even though on my SQL Server context I have:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
      // etc.
}
```

Both of my connection strings are good.

During one request I may need to access both databases is this doable?

Any hints, guides?

Thanks in advance
T

Comment: Are you using the `<connectionStrings>` section of a .config file? If so, have you verified that you're using the correct provider?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes and yes. On the mySQL conn string I have "MySql.Data.SqlClient" and on the MSSQL conn string I have "System.Data.SqlClient" also have them in the providers section of the entityF web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So best as I can understand as of EF 6.3 this is not something you can do. Possibly you may be able to do this, but not easily.

You can connect to many databases as long as they are of the same type.

You can't connect to one MySQL db and another MS-SQL db.

Comment: I've managed to accomplish this by setting up one project for each database. In your case you would have one for MySQL and another for MSSQL. You can then provide data access methods on each project that will retrieve the data and call these from a separate (business/service layer) project.

Comment: @jcruz Hi yup, that is what I _try_ to do. One proj for MSSQL-DAL and one for MySQL-DAL  is the idea. I still have two data access layers, one of then I'm just basically using ADO.NET, and for the other one I use EF. The db that i only read from gets to be the ADO.NET one.